# Dynamic parameter JSON to WHERE in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, object

I have JSON Response Request and want make one variable $Where from them, this the JSON pattern :

```
"filter":
{"filters":[
    {"logic":"and","filters":[
        {"field":"NAMA","operator":"eq","value":"Rahmat"},
        {"field":"NAMA","operator":"eq","value":"Rosadi"}
    ]},{"logic":"or","filters":[
        {"field":"NIPK","operator":"eq","value":"1919191919"},
        {"field":"NIPK","operator":"eq","value":"818181818181"}
    ]},{"logic":"and","filters":[
        {"field":"JK","operator":"eq","value":"P"},
        {"field":"JK","operator":"eq","value":"L"}
    ]}
],
"logic":"and"}
```

Can anyone tell me how make thats patter to singgle row PHP variable like this :

```
$Where = "(NAMA = 'Rahmat' or NAMA = 'Rosadi') and (NIPK = '1919191919' or NIPK != '818181818181') and (JK='P' AND JK='L')"
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: first of all, that is not valid JSON. You can use [www.jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON, and then try [http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) 

If you can't get it working, add the code you've tried running to this question by editing it. It is much easier and pleasing to help when we can see that you have given it a sweat yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the `filters` list into PHP arrays, building each of them as a list of SQL OR values, then join them with `implode(' OR ', ...)`; and further implode the arrays in a list of ' AND ' clauses.

This approach loses much of the flexibility allowed from your JSON setup, though; it can be extended to an `AND`-list of either `OR`-clauses or single clauses, and maybe coalesce `OR` clauses for the same field using the `IN` syntax, but not much more.

You can look to algorithm that convert from RPN notation to algebraic to look for a more powerful (albeit more complex) approach.

The simple version is

```
$ops = array(
    'eq' => '=',
    'ne' => '!=',
    'gt' => '>',
    'lt' => '<',
    'ge' => '>=',
    'le' => '<=',
    // CHECK THIS OUT, FIX & COMPLETE
);

$arr_Filters = array();
foreach($filters as $filter)
{
    /* $filter is a set of subfilters:
       {"logic":"and","filters":[
          {"field":"NAMA","operator":"eq","value":"Rahmat"},
         {"field":"NAMA","operator":"eq","value":"Rosadi"}
       ]},
       which we see as:
    */
    $logic = $filter['logic'];
    $arr_Filter  = array();
    foreach($filter['filters'] as $fov)
    {
        $op_f = $fov['operator'];
        $op   = $ops[$op_f];
        $value = /* FUNCTION TO SQL ESCAPE A VALUE */ $fov['value'];
        $value = is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'".$value."'";
        $arr_Filter[] = "$fov[field] $op $value";
    }
    $arr_Filters[] = '('.implode(' ' . $filter['logic'] . ' ', $arr_Filter).')';
}
$sql_filter = 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $arr_Filters);
```

Using `json_decode()` an object can be retrieved that can be manipulated thus:

```
// ($ops omitted, same as above)

$arr_Filters = array();
foreach($filters->filter->filters as $filter)
{
    /* $filter is a set of subfilters:
       {"logic":"and","filters":[
          {"field":"NAMA","operator":"eq","value":"Rahmat"},
         {"field":"NAMA","operator":"eq","value":"Rosadi"}
       ]},
       which we see as:
    */
    $logic = $filter->logic;
    $arr_Filter  = array();
    foreach($filter->filters as $fov)
    {
        $op_f = $fov->operator;
        $op   = $ops[$op_f];
        $value = /* FUNCTION TO SQL ESCAPE A VALUE */ $fov->value;
        $value = is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'".$value."'";
        $arr_Filter[] = "{$fov->field} $op $value";
    }
    $arr_Filters[] = '('.implode(' ' . $filter->logic . ' ', $arr_Filter).')';
}
$sql_filter = 'WHERE ' . implode(' ' . $filters->filter->logic . ' ', $arr_Filters);
```

Comment: ``Invalid argument supplied for foreach()``
at ``foreach($filter['filters'] as $fov)``